# Finding manufacturer of product based on certifications

Tags: manufacturing, certification, ul

I really do not know where to ask this question so I am starting here. If you believe there is a better place let me know and I will gladly move post.

I bought an induction cooktop from amazon and trying to figure out who is the manufacturer of this cooktop. The cooktop is a [Warmford 240V, 3500W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RTTNWPX). However, there is no company named Warmford or company associated with a brand called Warmford (at least that I could find from an extensive search). Interestingly, enough more search results appear when you search Warmfod. I nearly gave up trying to find the manufacturer when I saw this sticker on the bottom of the cooktop.

[image]

My thought was that maybe I can find the company if I am able to look up their certification details. After doing some googling, I came across the website for [Intertek](https://www.intertek.com/directories/) which has a product directory. I went to the ETL directory, but even after going through this method I was unable to find the manufacturer.

This leads me to three possible thoughts:

1. This sticker is fake and they are not actually certified.
2. I am looking at the wrong place or have a wrong understanding about the certifications. If this is the case I am hoping someone could possibly take a look at the directories and point me in the right direction.
3. There is no way to find the manufacturer of this induction cooktop the way I am going about it. If this is the case any ideas of a direction that I could take would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried searching that name on AliBaba/Banggood etc?

Comment: What does it mean to be the manufacturer?  The company where the people who originally designed the original version of it worked at the time?  The company that runs the factory that some lot of them were made in?  The company that imported and sold it?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Companies like GE or Nike don't even import and sell themselves - they just license other people to manufacture, label, import and sell under their brand. So, there's that fourth option.

Comment: I wouldn't expect Intertek to reveal the name of their customer. It might not be the manufacturer, importer, designer or vendor anyway. Why do you want to know who the manufacturer is?

Comment: Intertek may, however, verify that the approval code relates to the actual product it's fixed to if you think it's fake. There's an email enquiry address on their web site.

Comment: Yeah, intertek doesn't even need to know. They know who gave them money to run tests and write a report. That report might be in a FCC ID database. That's all their job.

Comment: By the way, "not actually certified": Is this an intentional *radiator*? If not, why should it even need certification?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's an induction hob, its job is to radiate energy! Besides, all electrical products will need some sort of certification.

Comment: @Finbarr I don't agree; its job is not to *radiate* energy, but to directly couple it in extreme near field, magnetically. It's closer to a carrera transformer than to a cordless phone.

Comment: (@Finbarr also, I don't know US regulations, where FCC is relevant. Non-radiating, non-medical isolated devices don't need any external certification in the EU, only the CE self-certification of compliance. I'm also a bit confused why a device sold in Korea needs to have FCC certification...)

Comment: (forget what I said about Korea; turns out amazon thought I was in east Asia for some reason.)

Comment: I believe the ETL listing only pertains to the UL and CSA standards listed below the mark. The product may need certification as a non-intentional RF radiator, but that is usually a self-certification. If you enter a recognized name in the ETL search the search will return some listings. I put in DeLonghi and got back a number of DeLonghi and other names and locations. When I clicked on one of the names with China locations, I got a list of product descriptions and model numbers and trade names including DeLonghi. I couldn't find the model number for the product I have.

Comment: ETL calls the number that is marked below the ETL mark a control number. It is unique to the manufacturing site for each applicant. I could not find an online search for control numbers. ETL certainly has a way to determine if the label information is consistent with the labelling agreement.

Comment: Wow, lots of comments. Let’s start from the top and work our way down. 

@Brian Drummond Yes I have tried Alibaba/Aliexpress/Banggood and there are plenty of induction cooktops but none that match the one I posted above.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I am looking for any information. In my mind when I say manufacturer I am talking about the company that the induction cooktop is being built. However, the people who originally designed it would be great but that’s a far reach to find that.

Comment: @Finbarr I thought the same thing about Intertek. However if you look at product directories it lists the name of the company and some information. I plan on sending an email tomorrow to them.

Comment: @Charles Cowie I pretty much did the same thing I searched induction and the certifications and results came up but nothing matching the model number of the device that I have.

Comment: If you search UL-197 you will find about 470 listings of commercial electric cooking appliances. Adding the word China yields a smaller list Adding all or part of the model number, variations of Warmford, Warmford, Warmfod, etc. yields nothing. I suspect that either the label is fake or more incorrect than I can guess or the listing agreement was cancelled and ETL deleted the record or hid it.

Comment: @Charles Cowie you have pretty much come to the same conclusion I have. I am going to email Intertek tomorrow and see if they have any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This sticker is fake and they are not actually certified.

This is actually quite common these days. I have bought a few power supplies with fake ETL tags, many items from china do. It is expensive to pass ETL and can be thousands to tens of thousands USD.

You check with the ETL, which in this case would be intertek (I am very sure that they keep records of the testing, I've never worked with Intertek but the ETL's I use do). The [intertek form is here](https://www.intertek.com/business-assurance/certificate-validation/). The second place is the manufacturer which should also have record.

It has a serial number, so that's a good sign.

Interestingly enough retailers are the ones who are supposed to enforce the ETL marks, they are not to sell products that don't have a correct ETL sticker. Your local fire warden is most likely also interested that everything you own is safe.

Comment: Why does the selected answer have 0 votes?

Comment: It was probably a new user when the question was written, in that case they can't vote until they get some rep (I think)

Answer (score 2):

The actual company is called Getrom.  To find the model replace the wf with JDL in the model number.   They actually do have ETL certifications, but this Warmford company is made up.
getrom.com.cn

Answer (score 1):

FCC marks are universally faked due to lack of interest in enforcement overseas. This is a common problem with government administered marks - the government can't justify spending citizens' tax dollars on overseas legal adventures, as they have no reputation to defend.

This is why private, independent testing labs certify equipment - BSI, TÜV, CSA, UL, etc.  They were once national monopolies, but trade treaties opened that up, and the list of *Recognized* testing labs (NRTLs) is maintained by USA OSHA and many entities defer to that list.   The burden of such a listing is considerable, and even includes ongoing factory inspections to assure continued compliance.

**ETL is on that list**.  To be recognized, they must aggressively defend that mark worldwide, including in China, which solves the flaw in FCC, CE, RoHS and other widely faked marks.   A proper NRTL mark will include a **file number** and the file number here is 4002064.   You should be able to take that file number back to ETL and ask them if the item is legit and who the manufacturer is. Manufacturers do not share file numbers. If it's fake, ETL may want to know more.

In general, buying AC mains electrical equipment via mail-order is risky. The [Amazon Marketplace business model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCTiU2ZHVwI) (including cross-listing items on eBay and using Amazon Fulfillment) has flooded mail-order with dangerous goods. Retail shops face consequences for selling non-NRTL-listed items - so better to buy at retail shops or their websites such as homedepot.com or wickes.co.uk (beware: some fold in Amazon or eBay results).  Or buy legit brands [off eBay.](https://www.cnbc.com/2022/06/17/the-fight-against-stolen-products-on-amazon-and-facebook-marketplace.html)